# how to create log in password in vb encrypted

Tags: vb.net, linq

Hi i have been searching the internet for 3 weeks now on how to create a log in interface with encrypted password . I was a to encrypt the text box for password but I dont know how to implement it . I am using linq to sql dbml to connect to my data based on text only I was able to get it can create but I want it to be more secure and more professionally looking with encrypted one. By the way I used wizard for creating database not hard coded it that is the way I know how to do it. I am totally noob in programming any help will do. Thanks

Public Class User_Log_In_v7
    Dim admin As New GeneralsDataContext

```
Private Sub User_Log_InBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Me.Validate()
    Me.User_Log_InBindingSource.EndEdit()
    Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.User_Log_In_DataSet)

End Sub

Private Sub User_Log_In_v7_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'User_Log_In_DataSet.User_Log_In' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    'Me.User_Log_InTableAdapter.Fill(Me.User_Log_In_DataSet.User_Log_In)

End Sub

Private Sub btnLogIn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnLogIn.Click
    Try
        Dim check = From Storage In admin.User_Log_Ins _
                  Where UsernameTextBox.Text = Storage.Username And PasswordTextBox.Text = Storage.Password

        If Not check.Count = 0 Then
            Membership_Information.Show()
            Me.Hide()
            UsernameTextBox.Text = ""
            PasswordTextBox.Text = ""
        Else
            MsgBox("Please check username or password and try again", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "")
            UsernameTextBox.Text = ""
            PasswordTextBox.Text = ""
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

This is the code I can from another tutorial for encrypting

Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.Text

Public Class Form1
    Dim DES As New TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider
    Dim MD5 As New MD5CryptoServiceProvider

```
'hash function
Function MD5Hash(value As String) As Byte()
    Return MD5.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value))
End Function

'Encryption
Function Encrypt(input As String, Key As String) As String

    DES.Key = MD5Hash(Key)
    DES.Mode = CipherMode.ECB

    Dim buffer As Byte() = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input)

    Return Convert.ToBase64String(DES.CreateEncryptor().TransformFinalBlock(buffer, 0, buffer.Length))


End Function
```

Comment: Passwords should be hashed not encrypted.  The easiest thing would be to get BCrypt.  MD5 is antiquated

Comment: As far as implementing it. You pass the password into your hash method and store the result in the database. Then when you want to check you take what the user types, pass that into your has method and compare this current hash to what is stored in the database to ensure they are the same. This is why it is important to make the user type the password twice (to ensure they didn't make a typo when entering their original password to be hashed.) Another thing to do upon an unsuccessful result is to not explicitly tell the user which failed.

Comment: Thanks guys for the quick respond favor Sir can you please give an example how to use bcrypt with my current database structure using linq to sql to access database for user account, I like to use your suggestion to hash the password and once user want to log in on password text box it will compare hash codes if you dont mind , the current database I have is only can save string with the actual password text which I know very high risk with hackers. I used wizard for creating database. Cheers.